# Adding constraint violation manually

Tags: java, bean-validation

Is it possible to add constraint violation manually?

E.g.:

```
// validate customer (using validation annotations)
Set<ConstraintViolation<Customer>> violations = validator.validate(customer);

if (someSpecialCase) {
    violations.add(..) 
}
```

The problem is the `add` method accepts a ConstraintViolation interface but the javax.validation package contains no implementors that can be used.

Any idea?

Comment: Which package are you using? This is not in standard java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: "No, there is no way to manually add constraint violations".

To elaborate a little bit. As you say, all classes involved are interfaces. If you really think you want to do it, you could implement your custom *ConstraintViolationImpl*. However, I am wondering what your actual use case is? Why do you want to add a constraint violation without validation? As the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23727169/115835 suggest, you could always go via a class level custom constraint. As part of *isValid* in your custom *ConstraintValidator* implementation, you get an *ConstraintValidatorContext* which will allow you to add additional constraint violations.

Comment: OK, basically what I want to do is make some field not-updateable. So based on the REST action (create vs. update) this validation should happen or not.

Comment: @MarcelOverdijk, then you should take a look at validation groups.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you're using Hibernate validators for this.

If that's the case, then depending on the special case you have, you would want to write a custom class-level validator for a `Customer` instead, and let it be captured in the set of constraint violations.

Since I don't know what your `Customer` bean looks like, I can only at best offer you a general direction on this approach.

```
// Annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomerValidator.class)
public @interface ValidCustomer {
    String message() default "Invalid customer (due to edge case)";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}

// Validator

public class CustomerValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCustomer, Customer> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ValidCustomer constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Customer value,
                           final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // logic for validation according to your edge case
    }
}
```

You would then annotate your `Customer` class with this validator.

```
@ValidCustomer
public class Customer {
    // ...
}
```

After this, your specific constraint will be captured in `violations`.

Comment: Yes I understand I can add custom validations like this. What I want to achieve is that a particular field of my entity cannot be updated once created. The validation framework has no notion that it is a context of updating. Any suggestions?